# How to transfer information between components in vue

Tags: vue.js, components

I want to search for products, my data is in categories container The structure of the project is attached
My question is how searchItem takes the relevant information from categoriesContainer
[data is in categories container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQAvP.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Vuex

Comment: ok thanks i do that.

Answer (score 0):

### Here are a few options

**For a global data access:**

Use Vuex: A state management (central store) that can serve data to any component at any point in time.

**For Component to component**

You can use props when importing a component into another.

**PS:** I will recommend you use state management to handle and transfer such "search result data" because as your app grows, i reckon other components other might need that same data as well. Which will minimize the amount of code you need to write.